# Application Page throws exception when code behind is added

Tags: central-administration, application-pages

I created an Application page within the Central Administration. Then I added some Controls to it (TextBox, Button - all ASP controls). Then I tried to add an event handler for the button click event. After that the page throws an exception - nothing very useful, it just says that it can not find the method:

Here is some sample code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="BtnSave_Click" />

protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff            
}
```

What I checked:

- The namespaces are correct.
- The *.aspx file Inherits from the correct class.
- The Page_Load method is executed fine. The debugger goes in there and the code in it works fine. So the code behind file is not missing.
- There is no problem with the name of the method. I copied it.
- The designer file is generated ok.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1:**

Here is the entire code, for now it does nothing but still fails:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReminderTimerConfigurationPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="SomePath.ReminderTimerConfigurationPage" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="Button1"
        runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
Application Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >
My Application Page
</asp:Content>
```

And the CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

namespace SomePath
{
    public partial class ReminderTimerConfigurationPage : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button1.Click += BtnSave_Click;
        }

        protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newXml = TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

In the button click event handler the TextBox1 is null.

Another problem is that when I try to rename any of the controls it blows up completely: Object reference not set to instance of an object.

Comment: Just a method to troubleshoot.. Copy the existing code of BtnSave_Click , remove OnClick="BtnSave_Click" from aspx page and add btnSave.Click+=BtnSave_Click; page_load  in code behind.Press tab twice so that VS generates the eventhandler method.Paste the code into that method and try running.

Comment: Ok it no longer throws the exception and it enters the method but when I try to work with any of the controls on the page they are all null.

Comment: Can you post the code over here and explain what the code does .It will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I was using CKSDev to deploy my code, the problem was there. I tried the Visual Studio deploy, did an iisreset and it worked.